# Suggestions for developing Windows Service with C#

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am developing a distributed application where each distributed site will run a 2-tier winform based client-server application (there are specific reasons for not going into web architecture). The local application server will be responsible for communicating with a central server and the local workstations will in turn communicate with the local server.

I am about to develop one or more windows services to achieve the following objectives. I presume some of them will run on the local server while some on the local workstations. The central server is just a SQL Server database so no services to be developed on that end, just DML statements will be fired from local server.

Windows Service Objectives

1. Synchronise local data with data from central server (both end SQL Server) based on a schedule
2. Take automatic database backup based on a schedule
3. Automatically download software updates from vendor site based on a schedule
4. Enforce software license management by monitoring connected workstations
5. Intranet messaging between workstations and/or local server (like a little richer NET SEND utility)
6. Manage deployment of updates from local server to workstations

Though I have something on my mind, I am a little confused in deciding and I need to cross-check my thoughts with experts like you. Following are my queries -

1. How many services should run on the local server? 
   Please specify individual service roles.
2. How many services should run on the workstations?
   Please specify individual service roles.
3. Since some services will need to query the local SQL database, where should the services read the connection string from? registry? Config file? Any other location?
4. If one service is alotted to do multiple tasks, e.g. like a scheduler service, what should be the best/optimal way with respect to performance for managing the scheduled tasks 
   a. Build .NET class Library assemblies for the scheduled tasks and spin them up on separate threads
   b. Build .NET executable assemblies for the scheduled tasks and fire the executables

Though it may seem as too many questions in a single post, they are all related. I will share my views with the forum later as I do not want to bias the forum's views/suggestions in any way.

Thanking all of you in advance.

Comment: I'd definitely take a long look at WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) rather than doing a traditional Windows Service or Web Service for your scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How many services should run on the local server?

It depends on many factors, but I would generally go for as less services as possible, because maintaining and surveilling one service is less work for the admin than having many services.

> How many services should run on the workstations?

I would use just one, because this will make it a single point of failure. The user will notice if the service on the workstation is down. If this is the case only one service needs to be started.

> Since some services will need to query the local SQL database, where should the services read the connection string from? registry? Config file? Any other location?

I would generally put the connection string in the app.config. The .NET framework also offers facilities to encrypt the connection string.

> If one service is alotted to do multiple tasks, e.g. like a scheduler service, what should be the best/optimal way with respect to performance for managing the scheduled tasks a. Build .NET class Library assemblies for the scheduled tasks and spin them up on separate threads b. Build .NET executable assemblies for the scheduled tasks and fire the executables

b. is easier to design and implement. It gives you the possibility to use the windows scheduler. In this case you will need to think of the problem, when the windows scheduler starts the executable, when the previous start has not finished yet. This results to two processes, which may do the same. If this is not a problem then stay at that design. If it is a problem, consider solution a.

For solution a. have a look on [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) which offers you a lot of advanced scheduling capabilities. Also considering using [application domains](http://codebetter.com/blogs/raymond.lewallen/archive/2005/04/03/61190.aspx) instead of threads to make the service more robust.

If you don't get admin rights on the local server, think about means to restart the service without the service control manager. Give some priviledged user the possibility to re-initialize the service from a client machine.

Also think about ways to restart just one part of a serivce, if one service is doing mulitple tasks. For instance the service is behaving strangely, because the update task is running wrong. If you need to restart the whole service to repair this, all users may become aware of it. Provide some means to re-intialize only the update task.

Most important: **Don't follow any of my advices if you find an easier way to achieve your goals. Start with a simple design. Don't overengineer! Solutions with (multiple) services and scheduling tend to explode in their complexity with each added feature. Especially when you need to let the services talk to each other.**

Answer (score 1):

I dont think there is one answer to this, some would probably use just one service and other would modularize every domain into a service and add enterprise transaction services etc. The question is more of a SOA one than C# and you might consider read up on some SOA books to find your pattern.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your questions specifically, but one thing to consider is that you can run multiple services in the same process.  The `ServiceBase.Run` method accepts an array of `ServerBase` instances to start.  They are technically different services and appear as such in the service control manager, but they are executed inside the same process.  Again, just something to consider in the broader context of your questions.